# Creating folder based on txt file name

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to ask how could I make a directory based on the text file name
For example, I have a text file named Game,Board,Risk.txt
What I want to do is to create a folder within the folder like /Game/Board/Risk.txt from that name. This is what I got so far but I don't think it's accurate:

```
for file in $path; do
    if [[ "$file" = *,* ]]
    then
    mkdir -p "$file"
```

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks a lot! this explanation along with the code someone else did below helps me understand it a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) to replace `,` with `/` in the filename, and pass the result to `mkdir -p` ex. given

```
$ ls *,*,*.txt
Game,Board,Risk.txt  Game,foo,bar.txt
```

then

```
for f in *,*,*.txt; do mkdir -p "${f//,/\/}"; done
```

results in

```
$ tree Game
Game
├── Board
│   └── Risk.txt
└── foo
    └── bar.txt

4 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. This makes more sense than the one I have above. However, can you explain a little further to me the meaning of this "${f//,/\/}"? Appreciate a lot

Comment: @Nin it's the `${parameter//pat/string}` example from the link I provided, with `,` as `pat` and `\/` as `string`. The `/` in `string` needs to be escaped as `\/` because `/` is also used as the delimiter.